# Generate dummy variable with multiple levels in R

Tags: r

My question involves how to generate a dummy-variable from a character variable with multiple repeated characters in R. The number of times
that a certain character is repeated varies.
There are several questions about this topic, but none of them seem to address my specific problem.
Below is a minimal example of the data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("C/004","C/004","C/005","C/005","C/005","C/007", 
                    "C/007", "C/007"))
```

The result I expect is as follows:

```
  > df
         ID newID
    1 C/004     1
    2 C/004     1
    3 C/005     2
    4 C/005     2
    5 C/005     2
    6 C/007     3
    7 C/007     3
    8 C/007     3
```

I would like to have the resulting variable `newID` as of numeric class and not a factor and so I would not go for the function `factor(.., levels=...)`

since it results into a factor variable and besides I would be required to supply factor levels which are too many.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `as.numeric(factor(df$ID))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of ways

```
match(df$ID, unique(df$ID))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Or

```
as.numeric(factor(df$ID))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Or

```
cumsum(!duplicated(df$ID))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

All `factors` are numerics underneath.  Therefore, if you want a numeric, simply convert

```
  df$newID <- as.numeric(factor(df$ID))
```